# How to use textarea as input to check duplication and invalid?

Tags: php, html

My idea is to use a textarea to let the user copy email name address etc.... to it.
The copied data must have delimiter between each value.

However, my questions are:

1. How can i detect the delimiter used in copied data?
2. How to manipulate? Store each into different array according to the location? but what if there is some error between eg. if one row has one more entry eg. email name address adress2 when other are email name address

Actually i am doing some process from outlook express export txt file or data copied from excel sheet

For those outlook express export file, there are some spacing for each email that without name .So the problem is occur eg.

aa@aa.com name1 bb@bb.com cc@cc.com name2

---

Thanks for your kindly help.

Comment: thx for edit, it is something basic but when the data is inconsitent ( some delimiter has more spacing)it is diffuclt to manulipate. actually i am doing some process from outlook express export txt file or data copied from excel sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use explode for this (http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).
If you can ask the users to enter each piece of data on a new line, you can then split the textarea contents by the \n character:
e.g.

```
$myarray = explode("\n", $textarea_str);
```

Then each element of the array can be split by the delimiting comma:

```
foreach ($myarray as $row)
     $eachline[] = explode(",", $row);
```

Then validate the individual items that you've extracted from the delimited data as if they have come individually.

Comment: 1.)How to check the delimiter in my program instead of asking the user to input.

Comment: 2.) How to prevent if the delimiter is not inconsistent? E.g. The first one is using ',' and the other one is using ' '

Answer (score 0):

You have to explode(',', $_POST['emails]), then run trough that array and check/trim/validate-email all elements for proper format.

Answer (score 0):

you can pre inform the user ,email address must be separated by (ur delimitor may be comma and so).On php side just `explode(delimitor,$_REQUEST['text_area_name']);`

Comment: Because my idea is pre inform the user but not specific the delimiter use in it and the user would not input the demlimiter. It would be ideal if I can check it in my program

Comment: if you know that user is going to add email address only then you can check the delimitors as space,newline character or comma which is commonly used by user,and replace this occurance of characters by some character which lateron you can use to explode

Answer (score 0):

Oh, nice question . You are trying to find what is the delimiter used in the copied text . I cannot say a perfect solution, but you may create an algorithm like this .

1. Consider possible delimiters ex : , ' " | etc.
2. Explode the text with each delimiter in consideration . count the number of elements returned in each array
3. For , which delimiter you got the higher number of elements in array , may be used by the user
4. You can fine tune the code

This is a simple example .

Thanks

Comment: I am suspecting a potential problem: Since i am maniuplating email address, is it possible the algothrim will turn out  "@" or "." as the delimiter

Comment: No , @ won't be a delimiter . That is why i am not sure about the accuracy . But this is a basic function only .

Comment: Can I check end of line in the textarea using php?

Comment: You can count the number of chars using strlen() and find teh last char .